# How to raise a pull request without GitHub?

Tags: git

Assuming I am not using github and using just plain simple git, and I have cloned a repo, made code changes.

Now how do I raise a pull request?

Comment: pull requests are a github thing. git itself, you either push from one repo to another or you pull from another repo. To put it another way, a "pull request" is a github created user interface to do a "git pull somerepo somebranch". git itself doesn't have pull requests.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull

Comment: @gman, so what is the thing that the above user has commented please (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull)

Comment: AFAIK all it does is generate a message you can email to someone that says "run git pull url-to-your-repo..."